# Reset terminal on Mac OS? Help installing Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I was following "[Setup Ruby On Rails on
Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.9-mavericks)" for Mac OS to install Rails, and after installing Xcode and Homebrew, I tried to install Ruby and Rails.

After this line in the tutorial (what I believe was installing Ruby):

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.2.3
rbenv global 2.2.3
ruby -v
```

Whenever I open terminal I am greeted with this message:

```
# Load rbenv automatically by adding
# the following to your profile:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Then none of the code I enter does anything, it just adds a line space.

How can I reset my terminal so I can try this from the beginning?

Bash profile:

```
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init =)"; fi
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Comment: This is all wrong, why are you not installing rvm, its a must for any development machine

Comment: No, it's not wrong. RBENV is equally good (if not better) than RVM. You just need to add that line to your bash_profile.

Comment: Considering my only knowledge of rails was from codeacademy, probably because I'm new to it and don't really understand the install..

Comment: Adding an answer now that I hope helps.

Comment: Rbenv is very good :) Do you read these nice tutorials? https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack that's the exact tutorial I linked to, except I'm on 10.9 Maverick.

Comment: @ether I think you have a bad syntax in the bash_profile file. Check it out.

Comment: @AlexanderShlenchack added bash profile contents to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your terminal "simply" needs to know where to load RBENV.

In your main, user directory (`/Users/yourmacusername`) there is a hidden file called `.bash_profile` that you'll need to access.

One easy way to see and access these files (without revealing/hiding hidden files in OS X) is to use the open source text editor [TextMate](https://macromates.com) (or another text editor like it).

Open that file in the editor (i.e., TextMate) and add the line noted in your Terminal (`eval "$(rbenv init -)"`) to the end of the file.

Then open and close Terminal, which is a quick, easy way for it to reload your bash_profile data, or you can type: `source ~/.bash_profile` in the Terminal to manually reload it.

You probably have to redo the rbenv install and global commands first after Terminal reopens/reloads.

Once it's reloaded or reopened, you can type `which ruby` to ensure it's installed, etc. It'll output a directory for you if it's there.

Comment: added the `eval` part to bash, bash profile now looks like: `if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
eval "$(rbenv init -)"`  reinstalling rails as we speak..

Comment: Cool ... let me/us know how it goes! Hope it's got you on the right track ... and that you can start plugging away at Rails :)!

Comment: If it helps at all, here is what I have in my zsh config (I use zsh over bash but it's pretty similar): `### RBENV
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi`

Comment: `gem install rails -v 4.2.4` returns : `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.`

Comment: If you type `which ruby` what output do you get?

Comment: `/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89928/discussion-between-craig-kaminsky-and-ether).

Comment: By default `which ruby` will output the system Ruby, which isn't going to help. If rbenv is initialized, `rbenv versions` will return information about what Ruby is enabled. If rbenv is in control `which ruby` should return a path in your home directory ending with "`.rbenv/shims/ruby`".

Comment: That's what I was getting at ... in our chat room, we got him set up with rbenv taking over and he's all installed and running with 2.2.3!